# Google Python OAuth: Detect web page closed or timeout

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I created a Python program that uses `InstalledAppFlow.run_local_server` to pop a web browser to have the user authenticate. Happy path works fine (user authenticates and I get the credentials.)

However, if the user closes the web page without authenticating or just leaves it up, the program hangs forever waiting for the response from run_local_server.

So, two questions...

1. Is there a way to detect the user closed the web page without authenticating?
2. Is there a way to set a timeout for run_local_server so that it will return in x seconds if there is no response?

I've done a lot of Googling and found that run_local_server runs a simple WSGI HTTP server locally but cannot find anything about how to address the two questions above.

Here is the code snippet.

```
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(GOOGLE_CREDS_FILE, GOOGLE_API_SCOPES)
    google_credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Will hang here forever unless the user authenticates...
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still looking for it, see one solution [here](https://github.com/kuzmoyev/google-calendar-simple-api/issues/54#issuecomment-725794523). It uses [pebble](https://pypi.org/project/Pebble/).

The following example is by [Teraskull](https://github.com/Teraskull) using my [Google Calendar Simple API](https://github.com/kuzmoyev/google-calendar-simple-api) library:

```
from oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors import AccessDeniedError, MismatchingStateError
from gcsa.google_calendar import GoogleCalendar
from concurrent.futures import TimeoutError
from pebble import concurrent


@concurrent.process(timeout=60)  # Raise TimeoutError, if the function exceeds the given deadline (in seconds).
def create_process():
    return GoogleCalendar('primary', credentials_path='credentials.json')


def do_something():
    try:

        process = create_process()  # Return concurrent process.
        calendar = process.result()  # Wait for process result. Return calendar instance, or exceptions, if any were raised.

    # Catch exceptions, received from process result.
    except TimeoutError:  # If user did not log into Google Calendar on time.
        pass

    except AccessDeniedError:  # If user denied access to Google Calendar.
        pass

    except MismatchingStateError:  # If user attempted to login using an outdated browser window.
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but for anyone looking for a answer to this or similar issues:

`run_local_server` seems to now have a timeout_seconds parameter you can pass to set a time limit for the user to authenticate on the http server created.

```
        try:
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0, timeout_seconds=100)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

I do recommend wrapping it in a try, except since I don't think the timeout is handled that well in the library.

This is the error printed out that comes from the  `run_local_server` function:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Anyway, I just created a custom Error to return to the user telling them that the request to authenticate timed out.